# Running a java code in Web browser

Tags: java, web-applications

As a student, I have created a website where I host experiments. This experiments are nothing but source codes in java or c++. For example, If we have to develop a code for printing first 10 numbers then I will host a file named (say) "numbers.java" containing following code

```
import java.io.*;
class numbers
{
  public static void main( String args[])
  {
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
      system.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

This is just an example. I host such files and people do refer them while performing practicals.

But as a developer, I want to create playground similar to Google's playground. On this playground peoples can execute this codes online in web browser itself.

I know such codes can be executed with applets, or even can be rewritten in php for execution but still I don't want rewriting work I want to execte them as it is on web broswer. That simply means I want to run **.java** file in web browser.

So it is possible to run the java codes like on which is shown above in web browser. If it is possible then please suggest me the changes which I should make in above code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to run code in a browser, without the browser downloading the code? How does that work, exactly?

Comment: Without download means, visitor do not need to download java file manually and then run it trough any IDE like netbeans. I want to execute file in browser itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 6 or above you may want to take a look at [JSR 223](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/) (generic scripting for the JDK). Amongst other things, it allows you to run Java code as a script, for example when used with [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/intro.html).